# Grouping lookbehind pattern along with matching regex search pattern to substitute as a whole

Tags: python, regex, lookbehind

I have to search and replace a pattern with the following condition:
if a string "y=2" is found in a line and if it is either preceded or not preceded by "x=" then substitute, the matched string "y=2" with "x=1 y=2". I am trying with the following

```
line="hello x=7 y=2"
m = re.search(r"((?<=x=\d\s)|(?<!x=\d\s))y=2", line)
if m:
    s = "x=1 " + m.group(0)
    line = re.sub(m.group(0), s, line)
    print line
```

I am getting output as **hello x=7 x=1 y=2** which is different from my expected output: **hello x=1 y=2**

How to get the whole pattern including the lookbehind expression as a matched string? This will solve my problem.

```
m.group(0) always print y=1, and m.group(1) prints nothing
```

I want this to have the whole string "x=7 y=1" to make the substitution work properly

Comment: `if it is either preceded or not preceded by "x="` -- this is a tautology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need lookbehind pattern to do this. All the work is to substitute `y=2` or `x=\d y=2` to `x=1 y=2`, right?

```
line="hello x=7 y=2"
re.sub(r'(x=\d\s)?y=2', 'x=1 y=2', line)
```

Comment: what does regex "(...)?.." do? what is the significance of '?' symbol?

Comment: @IbrahimQuraish In python re, `?`, the question mark indicates to match 1 or 0 repetition, which could do the trick here. Also `*` could work here too.

Answer (score 1):

So, basically, if a line has `y=2` replace or prepend the preceding `x=` definition? If so, i suggest you change your algorithm to do just that:

1. If search for `y=2` is true, then
2. If search for `x=[0-9]` is true, replace with `x=1`;
3. Else, replace `y=2` with `x=1 y=2` (For optimization, you can store and use the initial search result for `y=2`.)